# Вылетает приложение Android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.perekluchenie.com.example.perekluchenie.AboutActivity
import com.example.perekluchenie.com.example.perekluchenie.ButtonsActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mAboutActivity: Button = findViewById(R.id.aboutButton)
        val mButtonsActivity: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonsScreenButton)

        mAboutActivity.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AboutActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        mButtonsActivity.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ButtonsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity - я не могу понять почему приложение вылеает при нажатии на любую кнопку
на всякий случай вот Manifest.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Perekluchenie"
        tools:targetApi="31">



        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```
````

Comment: в логах написано почему

Comment: ButtonsActivity не прописан в манифесте

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы приложение Android могло работать с Activity, их нужно прописывать в файле AndroidManifest.xml. У вас пока там лежит описание только MainActivity. Примерно так будет выглядеть AndroidManifest.xml, если в него добавить две другие ваши Activity (ButtonsActivity и AboutActivity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Perekluchenie"
        tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name=".ButtonsActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
</application>

</manifest>
```

Я не совсем поняла, в каких пакетах лежат две другие ваши Activity (ButtonsActivity и AboutActivity), потому что в import-е пишется com.example.perekluchenie.com.example.perekluchenie.AboutActivity. Если класс Activity находится не в корневом каталоге кода (com.example.perekluchenie), а в каком-нибудь пакете (подпапке), то в AndroidManifest.xml нужно записывать названия пакетов через точку и только потом сам класс.
То есть, для ButtonsActivity, если она в корневом каталоге, параметр android:name выглядит так:

```
android:name=".ButtonsActivity"
```

Если же ButtonsActivity лежит в папке "activities", например, то уже так:

```
android:name=".activities.ButtonsActivity"
```

А если сама папка "activities" лежит, скажем, в папке "view", то вот так:

```
android:name=".view.activities.ButtonsActivity"
```

Comment: Экспортировать все активити подряд - не самая хорошая идея.

Comment: @user7860670 почему?

Comment: @Котлеткаеее, они будут доступны для вызова извне приложения, что потенциально небезопасно.